# Why is SyncToy 2.1 install failing?

Tags: installation, sync, synctoy

The install seems to fail when it tries to install the Sync Framework. I looked in the log file and it says:

```
Process exited with code 1633
```

Comment: Basically just using this question to document a problem I ran into, and had to google for. Rather than ending up at some discussion forum answer, people can find this.

Comment: nice way of documenting things! It helps both yourself and others. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're using the corrent executable on the [download site](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=c26efa36-98e0-4ee9-a7c5-98d0592d8c52&displaylang=en#filelist). I accidentally used the x64 installer on a 32-bit machine.

Comment: Just for reference I found this myself at: http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en/synctoy/thread/df28da6b-7f38-46ab-be77-27bb3b064d2b